# how to get event listener not to ignore if the first element in the select menu is clicked

Tags: javascript

i have tried the traditional method of addEventListener **change** but if i click on the first element on the list it wont respond, it only works if i click on australia then india...

**HTML**

```
<select id="country" >
 <option value="india">India</option>
 <option value="australia">Australia</option>
 <option value="turkey">Turkey</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
var a = document.getElementById('country');
a.addEventListener('change', function() {
  alert(this.value);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a default `<option>` like the the following:

```
<option selected disabled>DEFAULT</option>
```

Or you can use a more direct event like "click"

```js
document.querySelector('#country').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 document.querySelector('#view').value = this.value;
});
```

```html
<output id='view'></output><br>
<select id="country" >
 <option value="india">India</option>
 <option value="australia">Australia</option>
 <option value="turkey">Turkey</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its working as expected, as per 'change event' works when HTMLElement changes its value. With your 'select' element, it will not change its value when you select the same value is already selected.

You can add a default 'Select your value...' or something else you want, to prevent this behavior and accomplish what you are looking for.

[HTMLElement: change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

```js
var a = document.getElementById('country');
a.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.value === 'default')
        return;
    alert(this.value);
}, false);
```

```html
<select id="country" >
   <option value="default">Select country</option>
   <option value="india">India</option>
   <option value="australia">Australia</option>
   <option value="turkey">Turkey</option>
</select>
```

Comment: any other javacript work around to this problem ? I have tried using this code but it wont work
`document.querySelectorAll("option").forEach(element => {  element.addEventListener("click", ()=> {   element.querySelector("option").text  
  }) 
})`
any reason why?

Comment: Because 'click' event doesn't fire on options, you need to add the listener to your 'select' and then, manage event delegation.